# Creating a parallax tableview header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to create a parallax table view header [like this one.](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/3aab9bc8e28dcde1a0fcd92eeac9d5ccf2507368/687474703a2f2f662e636c2e6c792f6974656d732f30353133307332723058316a3178314e3051336e2f73706f746966792d34382d31362d68616c662e676966) In this [example](https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout) a collection view is used, but I'm trying to stay clear of this. How can I recreate this with a table view? I want the user to:

1. Scroll the table view to the top of the header THEN scroll up and down through the cells.
2. When the user has scrolled back to the top of the cells, then the user can push the table view down and reveal the header again.

The problem I was having with the collection view was that if there were a lower amount of cells in the table view, the table wouldn't scroll up all the way. If the table view was populated off the screen then it would then scroll to the top and allow desired behavior.

1. Table view pushes above header (or background, whatever gives the same effect).

   2. User can scroll through cells with partial header showing like in example.
   3. When user wants to dismiss the tableview and reveal the header, he scrolls to the top of the cells and once user scrolls when the
      first cell is at top, the tableview pushes down and reveals the
      header again.

Thanks.